# How to generate a random permutation in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, permutation

What is the best way to generate a random permutation of n numbers?

For example, say I have a set of numbers 1, 2 and 3 (n = 3)

Set of all possible permutations: {123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321}

Now, how do I generate:

- one of the elements of the above sets (randomly chosen)
- a whole permutation set as shown above

In other words, if I have an array of n elements, how do I shuffle them randomly? Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
java.util.Collections.shuffle(List);
```

[javadoc link for `Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
java.util.Collections.shuffle(list);
```

It's worth noting that there are lots of algorithms you can use. Here is how it is implemented in the Sun JDK:

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {
        Object arr[] = list.toArray();

        // Shuffle array
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

        // Dump array back into list
        ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            it.next();
            it.set(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But the api says it works in linear time. Is it possible for us to achieve this in less than O(n) complexity?

Comment: @Shankar: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079633/random-permutation/3079642#3079642)

Comment: @Danny that's possible, but impractical.

Comment: @metdos can you elaborate? I believe it's the knuth shuffle, and he kind of wrote the book on algorithms. Literally.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess my problem is with the random generator. I created a list with length of 3, and I shuffled it 100000 times, and the results weren't satisfactory(is not close to uniform as much as I expect)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RubyCollect4J](https://github.com/wnameless/rubycollect4j)

```
Ruby.Array.of(1, 2, 3).permutation().toA().sample();
```

It did exactly what you asked for.
BTW, I am the author of this Java library.

Answer (score -2):

Do you ask about a permutation generator? Because your permutation set is missing two numbers. Anyway you may look at the permutations generator on http://www.merriampark.com/perm.htm

Comment: My bad! I changed it. But, I wanted the permutations to get generated randomly.