# How to pull elements from an enum without getting repetitions

Tags: java, enums

I've been trying to pull values from an enum and store them as a String in an array. However, depending on a variable, the values have to be unique, i.e. the same value can't be used twice.

I've used the following code to pull values:

```
public enum Colour
{
    ROOD, GEEL, GROEN, BLAUW, PAARS;

    public Colour getRandomColour(Random rn)
    {
        return values()[rn.nextInt(values().length)];
    }
}
```

However, this can give duplicate values.

It seems that the values of my enum refuse to be put in code blocks. Sorry!

EDIT:

```
for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) 
            code[i] = kleur.getRandomColour(rn).toString();
```

It fills up the array 'code'. The array-length depends on several factors but it will always be smaller than or equal to the amount of values in the enum.

Comment: Did you try with a set instead of an array?

Comment: it would be interesting to see the part where you call `getRandomColour` and push the value in your array

Comment: Do you want to get random [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of all your enum values? Because if you call `getRandomColour` more than there is values in your enum you must get duplicate value at least once.

Comment: Show your code where you "pull values from an enum".

Comment: [Java generating non-repeating random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16000196)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a random enum value continuously without getting the same value twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145766/generating-a-random-enum-value-continuously-without-getting-the-same-value-twice)

Comment: The difference is that due to the nature of my project, I have to use an array since it has to be 2-dimensional. The post Dukeling linked used an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could populate a list with all values from your `Colour` enum, shuffle, and then just access values sequentially:

```
List<Colour> colourList = Arrays.asList(Colour.values());
Collections.shuffle(colourList);
```

Then, just iterate the list and access the colors in order, which of course should be random since the collection was shuffled:

```
for (Colour c : colourList) {
    // do something with c
}
```

You could also go with your current approach, and store the colors into a set, rather than an ArrayList.  But the problem there is that you may draw a duplicate value any number of times, and the chances of that happening as the set increases in size will go up.

Comment: You have to use `List<Colour> colours = Arrays.asList(Colour.values());
    Collections.shuffle(colours);` instead of `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(Colour.values()));` since Collections.shuffle doesn't return any value.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to an Array rather than a list? The 2-dimensions are quite important in my project (or since I'm a java novice, i don't know a better way to do it yet).

Comment: I don't recall seeing two dimensions in your question, but you can just run what I suggested N times to generate N dimensions of random sets of enum values.  You could go with what you have, but using a set, but then you have to deal with needing to draw multiple times to get the next unique value.

Comment: I just realised, this specific array is 1-D rather than 2-D. My project is a game of Mastermind and I'm using a 2-D array for the board while this was about the solution. I just need the values. ArrayList it is then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary list to check if the new value already exist and continue to generate a new value until a unique is found.

```
for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
   String next = kleur.getRandomColour(rn).toString();
   List<String> tempList = Arrays.arrayAsList(code);
   while (tempList.contains(next);
     next = kleur.getRandomColour(rn).toString();
   }
   code[i] = next;
}
```

Comment: I found a  slightly better solution to my problem. Store the values as String in an array and use the indexes to reference that String.

Answer (score 0):

For those still wondering, I might have found a good solution. 
Store the values of the array in an ArrayList. Using a for-loop to pull a value from the ArrayList then remove that index, essentially eliminating duplicates.