# Java random without repetition

Tags: java, android, random

How can I implement an integer random, that can generate each number just one time but without repetition. I use this code in Android.

```
int random = Random.nextInt((max+1 - min) + min;
```

Problem: between max and min there is repeated numbers and also some numbers, they don't exist.

Comment: What do you need this for? In any case, you don't want to use `Random`, you should see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505927/how-to-generate-a-random-permutation-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a shuffle algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

create an array/list of the possible number, shuffle it, and then get the number once at a time

Answer (score 0):

instead of having a list (as mentioned from Derek Fung) with all possible values you

- can store created values in an list
- check if any new created value is in that list and then

  - add it to the list
  - or create a new value until you found one that is not in the list

Comment: Set would be better for that, wouldn't it?

Comment: @piezol depends on implementation, if it's a simple `java.util.List<Integer>` it might be enough to simply add these...