# Calculate when input parameter combination will match with loop iteration indexes

Tags: java, math

I have 3 integer as input: `a`, `b` and `c`.
I'm trying to create a function to calculate the number `progress` at which a match will occur.

I used the following code to output the number and then the combination of input numbers. I'm trying to create a function where I can input `a`, `b`, and, `c` and it will return the `progress` for which `x==a,`y==b`and`z==c`.

```
int progress = 0;
for (int x = 0; x <= 160; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y <= 160; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z <= 160; z++) {
            progress++;
            System.out.println(progress + " " + x + " " + y + " " + z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this triple loop?

Comment: are you basically looking for which numbers are NOT primes?

Comment: We can't help if we don't know what you want to do.

Comment: What is the `combination`you expect to occur?

Comment: It's just an example. What I'm trying to figure out is a formula for determining the point at which a combination of values would come up in a loop.

Comment: @bber For that you can just check x,y and z values where your have currently put print statement

Comment: what is a "combination of values"?

Comment: I understand, but I'm just looking for a math formula right now, nothing else. A "combination of values" as in an x y z combo.

Comment: do you want to get the possible permutation of the 3 numbers entered by the user? you may want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505927/how-to-generate-a-random-permutation-in-java

Comment: No. I want to be able to put in a combo of x, y, and z and it inputs out a value. An example would be putting in 40 40 102. That would output 1043383 from the formula.

Comment: how can 40 40 102 and 1043383 be related to each other? what would an expected output look like?

Comment: Run the code in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is:

```
progress = 1 + z_iterations
progress = 1 + z + 161*y_iterations
progress = 1 + z + 161*( y + 161*x_iterations )
progress = 1 + z + 161*( y + 161*x )
```

Final form:

```
progress = 1 + z + 161*y + 25921*x
```

You method should be:

```
public int computeProgress (int a, int b, int c) {
    return 1 + c + 161*b + 25921*a;
}
```